# String Replace with Regex in Java

Tags: java

```
String str1 = "S1,,?-";
String str2 = "R2'";
str1 = str1.replace("([A-Z][0-9]?)(?:\\.{1,2}|'{1,2})?", str2);
```

Expected output: `R2',,?-`
Actual Output: `S1,,?-`

In the above code, I want to replace the matching pattern in `str1` with `str2`.
All other strings will be retained in `str1`. The `str1` is a `string` and always starts with specific pattern having one alphabet followed by one digit followed by one or two dots or on or two quotes or none. After this `str1` may contain many other characters. `(Ex: S1..-,,, R2':--, G4''?, M2';; etc).` So the length of sub-string to be replaced is not known and hence I used pattern matcher `"([A-Z][0-9]?)(?:\\.{1,2}|'{1,2})?"`.
I am not able to make out why I am not getting expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead of [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). The former takes a regex, while the latter takes a normal string